# Check array items

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, loops, recursion

In the code below, $rows is a array value as a result of a MySQL query from the TestPhase table in the database.

```
<?php>
    $rows = array();

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TestPhase where Pid<10", $db) or die("cannot select");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
  $rows []= array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'parent' => $row['parent'],
    'name' => $row['name'],
  );

}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var treeData = <?php echo json_encode($rows); ?>;

</script>
```

This code is a snippet of the js file that is used to build a tree diagram using the results of the query and the values store in var treeData, that is, the $rows array.

```
function toTree(treeData) {
   var childrenById = {}; 
   var tnodes = {};        
   var i, row;
   // first pass: build child arrays and initial node array
   for (i=0; i<treeData.length; i++) {
       row = treeData[i];
       tnodes[row.id] = {name: row.name, children: []};
       if (row.parent == -1) { // assume -1 is used to mark the root's "parent"
          root = row.id; 
       } else if (childrenById[row.parent] === undefined) {
          childrenById[row.parent] = [row.id];
       } else {
          childrenById[row.parent].push(row.id);
       }
   }

   function expand(id) {
       if (childrenById[id] !== undefined) {
           for (var i=0; i < childrenById[id].length; i ++) {
               var childId = childrenById[id][i];
               tnodes[id].children.push(expand(childId));
           }
       }
       return tnodes[id];
   }
   return expand(root);
}

console.log(toTree(treeData));
```

I would like to run another sql query to check the TestOptions table to see if any of the records returned in the above query that make up the array $rows are also part of the this table. This would be as the each item in the $rows array, or each object in the array, may be connected to the TestOptions Table by a foreign key.

This is the table TestOption: `{optionID (PK);phaseID (FK-from TestPhase table); name}`

The query may go something like this:

`Select name from TestOption where phaseID IN (Select id from TestPhase);`

Basically if an item returned in the $rows array exits in the TestPhase table, it should be identified and the name should be printed.

If an item of the $rows array from the query to the TestPhase table is connected to the TestOptions table, I would like to make that know by printing the name value stored in the name attribute of the TestOptions table.

How do I do this? How do i make this check on each item of the array?

Comment: Why not use `JOIN` in your SQL?

Comment: I cant use a join. The first $rows array is used to build one diagram, and I need this data to build another tree.